# Replace single quote with double quote with Regex

Tags: java, regex

I have an app that received a malformed JSON string like this:

```
{'username' : 'xirby'}
```

I need to replaced the single quotes `'` with double quoates `"`

With these rule (I think):

- A single quote comes after a `{` with one or more spaces
- Comes before one or more spaces and `:`
- Comes after a `:` with one more spaces
- Comes before one or more spaces and `}`

So this String `{'username' : 'xirby'}` or

```
{  'username' : 'xirby'  }
```

Would be transformed to:

```
{"username" : "xirby"}
```

Update:

Also a possible malformed JSON String:

```
{  'message' : 'there's not much to say'  }
```

In this example the single quote inside the message value should not be replaced.

Comment: Don't use a regex for that, see my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
\s*\'\s*
```

and a call to Replace with `"` will do the job. Look at [here](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Cs%2a%5C%27%5Cs%2a&i=%7B%20%20%27username%27%20%3a%20%27xirby%27%20%20%7D&r=%5C%22).

Answer (score 3):

Instead of doing this, you're better off using a JSON parser which can read such malformed JSON and "normalize" it for you. [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind) can do that:

```
final ObjectReader reader = new ObjectMapper()
    .configure(Feature.ALLOW_SINGLE_QUOTES, true)
    .reader();

final JsonNode node = reader.readTree(yourMalformedJson);

// node.toString() does the right thing
```

Answer (score 2):

This regex will capture all appropriate single quotes and associated white spaces while ignoring single quotes inside a message. One can replace the captured characters with double quotes, while preserving the JSON format. It also generalizes to JSON strings with multiple messages (delimited by commas `,`).

```
((?<={)\s*\'|(?<=,)\s*\'|\'\s*(?=:)|(?<=:)\s*\'|\'\s*(?=,)|\'\s*(?=}))
```

I know you tagged your question for java, but I'm more familiar with python. Here's an example of how you can replace the single quotes with double quotes in python:

```
import re
regex = re.compile('((?<={)\s*\'|(?<=,)\s*\'|\'\s*(?=:)|(?<=:)\s*\'|\'\s*(?=,)|\'\s*(?=}))')
s = "{   'first_name'   :   'Shaquille'     ,    'lastname'   :   'O'Neal'     }"
regex.sub('"', s)

> '{"first_name":"Shaquille","lastname":"O\'Neal"}'
```

This method looks for single quotes next to the symbols `{},:` using look-ahead and look-behind operations.

Answer (score 1):

```
String test = "{'username' : 'xirby'}";
String replaced = test.replaceAll("'", "\"");
```

Comment: @flav my concern with replaceAll is that it might replace single quote inside as single quoted text

Comment: @xybrek hence the need to use a proper JSON parser... Regexes can only do so much

Answer (score 1):

Concerning your question's tag is **JAVA**, I answered in **JAVA**.

At first import the libraries:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
```

Then:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("((?<=(\\{|\\[|\\,|:))\\s*')|('\\s*(?=(\\}|(\\])|(\\,|:))))");
String s = "{   'firstName'   :   'Malus'     ,    'lastName'   :   ' Ms'Malus'     , marks:[   '  A+  ', 'B+']}";
String replace = "\"";
String o;

Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
o = m.replaceAll(replace);
System.out.println(o);
```

Output:

```
{"firstName":"Malus","lastName":" Ms'Malus", marks:["  A+  ","B+"]}
```

Comment: This works well even when we have single quote inside the value. ex: { 'name': "man's" }

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to exactly satisfy all of those conditions, try this:

```
'{(\s)?\'(.*)\'(\s)?:(\s)?\'(.*)\'(\s)?}'
```

as you regex. It uses (\s)? to match one or zero whitespace characters.