# JSON data in single quote

Tags: java, json

I have an expiry date in JSON formate and I want to get this expiry date in string variable so what should I do? 
    public class ExpiryDate {

```
    public String getExpiryDate() throws ParseException, IOException{

        String expiryDateString = "{'expire_on':'Aug 05, 2016'}";

        JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

        Object obj = jsonParser.parse(expiryDateString);

        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;

        System.out.println(jsonObject);

        return "";
    }

}
```

I am passing this JSON data but at Object create line i got this exception

```
Unexpected character (') at position 1.
    at org.json.simple.parser.Yylex.yylex(Unknown Source)
    at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.nextToken(Unknown Source)
    at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at onbording.ExpiryDate.getExpiryDate(ExpiryDate.java:25)
    at onbording.Sendmail.handleRequest(Sendmail.java:57)
    at example.sendmailTest.testsendemail(sendmailTest.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

Comment: I see two clear options: escape double quotes (single ones are not allowed in JSON) or use JSONObject to make the generation simpler.

Comment: yupp now i got it @Pablo by removing single quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You can't use single quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275359/jquery-single-quote-in-json-response).

You're probably using Java. I would suggest you to use [JSONObject](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObject.html).

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
jsonObject.put("expire_on", "Aug 05, 2016");
String expiryDateString = jsonObject.toString();
```

It's usually better practice to handle JSON like this than creating JSON string manually.

Another option is to use escaped double quotes.

```
String expiryDateString = "{\"expire_on\":\"Aug 05, 2016\"}";
```

Comment: Thank you @yariash but I have JSON data as explain above coming from Database and by this string i want the only date

Comment: If that string is stored in your DB, then you have invalid JSON in your DB

Comment: If i use double quote instead of single quote than i will get syntax error on token

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17009265/replace-single-quote-with-double-quote-with-regex) would help you?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the API but from the looks of it you need to escape your ' characters ...

From a quick google search i found this: http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser

The code in the link basically tells you to use \" instead of ' in your String and your JSONParser should understand it. Hope this helps.